# DataGridView background color change only working on first tab

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabs

I have a tab control with three tabs. Each tab contains a DataGridView displaying data with the same format, but from different sources. The requirement is that each row in the grid has a different background color (which matches a chart of the data which is also displayed in the tab).

To avoid repeating the same block of code three times, I have a method which loads the data into the grid, and also constructs the chart from the data. It is of the form:

```
private void loadData(DataGridView theGrid, Chart theChart, int dataSource)
```

This is called with statements like:

```
loadData(onShoreView, onShoreChart, 1);
loadData(offShoreView, offShoreChart, 2);
loadData(globalView, globalChart, 3);
```

`loadData()` then retrieves the relevant data from the database, and builds a List which is assigned to the grid using:

```
theGrid.DataSource = dataList;
```

The section of the method that colors the rows is executed after the grid is filled:

```
        //Assign colors to rows - but not the total line
        for (int i = 0; i < theGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            theGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = theColors[i];
            theGrid.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

theColors has previously been defined as:

```
private Color[] theColors= {
                                Color.SteelBlue,
                                Color.IndianRed,
                                Color.LightGreen,
                                Color.Orange,
                                Color.PaleTurquoise,
                                Color.Gold,
                                Color.RosyBrown,
                                Color.MediumPurple,
                                Color.MidnightBlue,
                                Color.Pink
                            };
```

This works perfectly for the first tab - the grid lines have the correct colors, and the chart matches them. For the subsequent tabs, although the colors on the chart are correct, the grid is unaffected - the rows are all the same default color.

I have double and triple checked, and other than the name all the properties of the DataGridView objects on the second and third tabs are the same as the properties of the DataGridView on the first tab.

Can anyone suggest what might be happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to call the method "loadData" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to handel the event `SelectedIndexChanged` of your `TabControl` for call your method "`loadData`" just if the user has selected the tab , like that you can be quiet that your program is not a treatment that is not necessary , it's a benefit for performance :

```
  private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var grd = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x is DataGridView );

       var chrt = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x is Chart);
       //tabControl1.SelectedIndex=0 if first tab is selected
       //tabControl1.SelectedIndex=1 if second tab is selected
        int i = tabControl1.SelectedIndex+1;
        loadData((DataGridView)grd, (Chart)chrt, i);

    }
```

Comment: There should be more to this answer:  Only that first tab has been initialized fully.  When another tab is selected, it gets initialized.  The call to `LoadData` should be happening as tabs are selected, not up front.

Comment: Also, if there aren't other "types" of tabs in play, all of that Linq is just overhead for no good reason.  Simplicity will gain even more efficiency, if that is your goal.

Comment: 'Should' is not necessarily what is. TabPages are notorious for not getting all/any visual updates when not selected.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you - pulled off this project temporarily for something more urgent - but putting the loadData() call in the SelectedIndexChanged() and loading the data for the appropriate tab when it's first displayed did the trick. Thanks!